# preg_replace to get part of url

Tags: http, url, preg-replace

i currenting use **ereg_replace**

```
$myurl="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$theid= ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $myurl);
```

To get an id at the end of the url entered

Id like to use **preg_replace** and accomplish getting two types of ids

one looking like http:// site.com?id=64

like I do above

but I want to also get one that would contain http:// site.com?pick=7878787

I am trying to assign pick id's to one variable called $thepickupcode

and the other to a variable called $theid

Any help I am happy about.

Answer (score 1):

A non regex way:

```
$res = parse_url($myurl);
parse_str($res['query'], $query);
$theid = $query['id'];
$thepickupcode = $query['pick'];
```

A regex way:

```
if (preg_match('~(?<=[?&])(id|pick)=([0-9]++)(?=&|$)~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $match))
    if ($match[1] == 'id') $theid = $match[2];
    else $thepickupcode = $match[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but I think you want something like:

Then you want preg_match, not replace.

```
preg_match( '~(pick|id)=(.+)~i', $myurl, $res );
print_r( $res );
```

I am not sure what all the possibilities are, but this may be more appropriate:

```
preg_match( '~\?(pick|id)=([0-9]+)$~i', $myurl, $res );
print_r( $res );
```

Comment: That does not appear to do it ?
I have two possibles at the end of my site url
.com/?id=74 or .com/?pick=838390
The numbers change of course but I want to extract them in to Variables so I can direct the php to that id or that pick

Comment: Thank you for all the help  these were great learning examples to try and test with.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to change `ereg...` to `preg...`, you have to enclose the regex in delimiters.
For your example:

```
$theid= ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $myurl);
```

becomes:

```
$theid = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $myurl);
```

or

```
$theid = preg_replace("/\D+/", "", $myurl);
```

But this will give you wrong result if there are other numbers than the id.

I suggest you follow @CasimiretHippolyte 's answer.